# Excel: how to sum values in sheet2 based on whether a value in sheet1 matches value in sheet2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the formula I have written that isn't working:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!E:E,"E2",Sheet2!T:T)
```

*Sheet1* contains a list of person identifiers (column E). 
 
*Sheet2* contains rows that contain these identifiers and balances. 
One individual identifier (column E) will be in multiple rows with a variety of balances (column T).

I want to pull the sum of an identifier's balances into Sheet1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to change:

1. You say that your identifier column (E) is in Sheet1, but in the formula you've referenced Sheet2
2. To reference a value in a cell use `E2` rather than `'E2'`. I.e. no apostrophes

So hopefully this works now:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!E:E,E2,Sheet2!T:T)
```

Comment: I did not need to use make the change you mention in #1.  Sheet1 contained a column of person identifiers (i.e. Person 1, Person 2) in column E.  Sheet2 contained a column of the same person identifiers in E, along with a dollar value in another column T (i.e. Person 1 | $5; Person 1 | $8; Person 1 | $4).  I needed to pull the sum of T in Sheet2 for Person 1 into Person 1's row in Sheet1.  This is now working, thanks!